# Ошибка Спавна объектов на Android

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Создаю спавн объектов в случайных 3ёх позициях через определённое время = 2сек. Всё работает на компьютере. Перекидываю apk файл на телефон по USB. Тоже вроде более менее работает. Но вот перекидываю потом этот же файл с телефона через гугл диск на другой телефон и всё сбивается. Объекты перестают спавнятся каждые 2 сек, они начинают спавнятся просто все мгновенно без задержки времени 2 сек. Честно, не понимаю, в чём моя ошибка. Мб в коде спавна. Если кто-нибудь знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Код Спавна:**

```
    public GameObject[] сubeVariants;

    public float timeBtwSpawn;

    private void Start()
    {
        spawnCube();
        StartCoroutine(CubeWave());
    }

    private void spawnCube()
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, cubeVariants.Length);
        Instantiate(cubeVariants[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    IEnumerator CubeWave()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBtwSpawn);
            spawnCube();
        }
    }
```

Comment: timeBtwSpawn - это сколько?

Comment: Сделай начальное значение твоей переменной. Может значение в редакторе не занеслось в билд

Comment: Ошибка была не в спавнере объектов оказывается. Она была в скорости в том, что я задал движение, но как обычно не домножил на Time.deltaTime.